# pyside QTextEdit selected text event

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit widget layed out on the left and a QTextBrowser on the right, 
I am looking for a way to do the following:

1. the user select a some text
2. a function is triggered by this event
3. the selected text is processed
4. the processed text is displayed on the right

I have googled for it but didn't see relevant results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [selectionChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#selectionChanged) signal to trigger the function, and then retrieve the selected text via the [textCursor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#textCursor). The processed text can be displayed by using either [setPlainText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop), or, if you want to use markup, [setHtml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#html-prop). But note that `QTextBrowser` only supports a [limited subset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) of html/css.

Here's a demo script that shows how to put it all together:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.edit.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
        self.browser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)

    def handleSelectionChanged(self):
        text = self.edit.textCursor().selectedText()
        # process text here...
        self.browser.setPlainText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 600, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```